# Handling exceptions in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, try-catch

Is there a better way for handling exceptions ? Can I do the same thing but only with one try catch ?

Do I need to create my own exceptions class ?

```
try
{
   firstname = bd["firstname"].ToString();
}
catch (KeyNotFoundException fe)
{
   firstname = null;
}

try
{
   lastname = bd["lastname"].ToString();
}
catch (KeyNotFoundException fe)
{
   lastname = null;
}

try
{
   phone = bd["phone"].ToString();
}
catch (KeyNotFoundException fe)
{
   phone = null;
}

...
...
```

Comment: it's a BsonDocument variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use exceptions for normal program flow if possible:

```
firstname = bd.ContainsKey("firstname") ? bd["firstname"] : null;
lastname = bd.ContainsKey("lastname") ? bd["lastname"] : null;
phone = bd.ContainsKey("phone") ? bd["phone"] : null;
```

or (assuming you are accessing a `Dictionary`):

```
bd.TryGetValue("firstname", out firstname);
bd.TryGetValue("lastname", out lastname);
bd.TryGetValue("phone", out phone);
```

Comment: Since you have mentioned that `bd` is a `BsonDocument` you could replace `ContainsKey` with `Contains`.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I got ContainsValue, TryGetValue, TryGetElement what is the difference ?

Comment: @user2037696: I must admit that i have no experiences with mongodb, however, from the [documentation](http://mongodb-silverlight-driver.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Bson/ObjectModel/BsonDocument.cs) it seems that you have to use `Contains` if you want to know if the dictionary contains the given key(so like `ContainsKey`). So `TryGetValue` seems to be equivalent to `Dictionary.TryGetValue`.

Answer (score 1):

firstname =  Convert.ToString( bd["firstname"]);

lastname  = Convert.ToString( bd["lastname"]);

phone     = Convert.ToString(bd["phone"]);

Try Convert.ToString("string Value") method instend of  .ToString() to avoid Exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use try catch blocks with minimum overhead, You can write all the code in one try block and write multiple catch blocks.

```
try
{
   firstname = bd["firstname"].ToString();
   lastname = bd["lastname"].ToString();
   phone = bd["phone"].ToString();
}
catch (KeyNotFoundException fe)
{
   firstname = null;
}

catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
{
   lastname = null;
}


catch (KeyNotFoundException xe)
{
   phone = null;
}
```

Comment: Using the same exception type in multiple `catch` blocks will not work: only the first will be run.

Comment: what if i have different exception objects?

Comment: Just checked: this is a compiler error (.NET 4.5/C#5). Use of different identifiers makes no difference.